# Confirm Dialog appear two twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog, primeng

I'm using primeng in my project. I have a mat-tab with the same component inside the both, this component is a form with a button that when I press shows a confirm dialog. The problem is, when I press the button to show de confirm dialog, appears in both tab. How can I resolve this issue?

```
    confirmPrinting(event: Event) {
      this.confirmationService.confirm({
          target: event.target as EventTarget,
          message: 'Are you sure with' + this.printSelected +'?',
          header: 'Confirmación',
          icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
          acceptIcon:"none",
          rejectIcon:"none",
          rejectButtonStyleClass:"p-button-text",
          accept: () => {
               this.messageService.add({ key: 'tc',severity: 'info', summary: 'Confirm', detail: 'Starting print...' });
             
          },
          reject: () => {
              this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Cancel', detail: 'Print canceled', life: 3000 });
          }
      });
  }
```

This is the html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn mat-btn" [disabled]="printDisabled" (click)="confirmPrinting($event)"><mat-icon class="tab-icon">print</mat-icon></button>
```

I would like the confirmation dialog to only appear once, I need them to be independent.

Comment: Can you add the html code as well?

Comment: @Fseee I just added the main component html code. In each tab I add the child component, it is also in these tabs that the modal dialog appears, no matter if I click on one tab or the other, the dialog appears in both tabs.

Comment: Can you please provide also the code where <p-confirmDialog></p-confirmDialog> is placed? Is it in the app-print component?

Comment: @Fseee added. I have only added the code that may be relevant, maintaining the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

```
<p-confirmDialog></p-confirmDialog>
```

is part of app-print component and it is included twice, then when you call confirmation.confirm it will trigger the confirm dialog to be opened in both of the components, so you got twice.

Remove `<p-confirmDialog>` from app-print ad add it to the main component.

Comment: I've tried it but it keeps doing the same thing. I have added it in the main component in each of the tabs.

Comment: If there's one in each of the tab then there are two, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I edited the html main component code post. Appears the modal in one tab and when i change the tab there is a modal in the other tab.

Comment: You must have only one <p-confirmDialog></p-confirmDialog>, I still see two of them, otherwise you should use a key to target one or other

Comment: Finally i did with key, because i needed  one<p-confirmDialog></p-confirmDialog> for each tab, i think. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you doing something like this.

calling the onSave on (ngSubmit) and from the button.

```html
<form #form1="ngForm" *ngIf="organizationHierarchyItem" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
<button type="submit" (click)="onSave()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm margin-btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i'm only calling the confirmPrinting on the button.